# UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods causing crash after changing to UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, collections, view

I've recently altered my collectionView so that it is within a CollectionViewController and not within a view within a ViewController.
When I attempt to save photo or select photo from library to appear in the collectionView and also be saved in to the album (if photo taken) it crashes with:

Latest[9553:146224] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It works fine in my other project which is a collection view within a view controller.

The problem is definitely in the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Method but I can't work out what.

Here is the code for the project in which it is failing

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class GalleryViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var imageArray = [UIImage]()
var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
let albumName = "Test"
var albumFound : Bool = false
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!
let reuseIdentifier = "PhotoCell"



@IBAction func btnPhotoAlbum(_ sender: Any) {

    let picker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}



@IBAction func btnCamera(_ sender: AnyObject)  {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera){
        //load the camera interface
        let picker : UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        //no camera available
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "There is no camera available", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: {(alertAction)in
            alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)

    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
    if let _:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{

        //found the album
        self.albumFound = true
        self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject! as PHAssetCollection

    }else{
        var albumPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
        //create the folder
        NSLog("\nFolder \"%@\" does not exist\nCreating now...", albumName)
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: self.albumName)
            albumPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
        },
                                               completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                                                if(success){
                                                    print("Successfully created folder")
                                                    self.albumFound = true
                                                    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
                                                    self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject! as PHAssetCollection
                                                }else{
                                                    print("Error creating folder")
                                                    self.albumFound = false
                                                }
        })
    }









}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {


    self.imageArray.removeAll()
    grabPhotos()


}





func grabPhotos(){

    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]


    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options: fetchOptions) {
        if fetchResult.count > 0 {

            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{

                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width:200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {

                    image, error in

                    self.imageArray.append(image!)


                })
            }

            self.collectionView!.reloadData()


        }
        else{
            print("you got no photos!")



        }


    }
}









override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}





//UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods


func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){

    if let image: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{



            PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                let createAssetRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                let assetPlaceholder = createAssetRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
                if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset) {
                    let fastEnumeration = NSArray(array: [assetPlaceholder!] as [PHObjectPlaceholder])
                    albumChangeRequest.addAssets(fastEnumeration)                     }
            }, completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                    NSLog("Adding Image to Library -> %@", (success ? "Sucess":"Error!"))
                    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
    }
}




    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line of code causes the crash?

Comment: if let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection, assets: self.photosAsset) {

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure this has to do with the `UIImagePickerController`, because it's actually working if it reaches that point. Without knowing anymore and based on what you've written, I would guess that your `photosAsset` property is `nil` at this point. You set the property as a force-unwrapped optional, but never actually give it any value as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the response Pierce. I am going about this the wrong way? Is there a better way of fetching the image/taking the photo and displaying it?

Comment: I can't tell exactly what special process you're trying to complete. If you just want to display the image that the user took/picked, you already have it there when you say `if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage { }`. If that's all you're trying to do, just use that for the image property of a `UIImageView`

Comment: I'd like to add the image picked/taken into the collection view